# Transforming matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I came across following matrix equations:

> $(w^*)^TX^TX=y^TX \quad\quad\quad...\text{equation(1)} $
> $(X^TXw^*=X^Ty) \quad\quad\quad...\text{equation(2)}$

All $X,w^*$ and $y$ and matrices or vectors. And ${x}^T$ means transpose of $x$. Then how equation(1) leads to equation(2)? Is it purely through matrix algebra or is there any calculation based on context (which I havent specified in this problem hoping it to be purely based on matrix algebra)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a general rule of matrix multiplication that
$$
(A\cdot B)^{\tau} = B^\tau \cdot A^\tau
$$
Multiplication by a vector is matrix multiplication, too.

Comment: Like this?: $((w^∗ )\color{red}{(X^T X)})^T=(y^T X)^T →(X^T X)^T (w^∗ )^T=X^T {y^T}^T → X^T {X^T}^T  (w^∗)^T=X^T y →X^T X(w^∗ )^T=X^T y$. That red grouping is essential right?

Comment: Yes. Except that you should decide whether you start with $\omega^*$ or $(\omega^*)^\tau$.

Comment: ohh, ok I made mistake there. Its $(w^*)^T$ only as in original question. By mistake I took $(w^*)$ in above comment.